# IBM Form Experience Builder V 8.6 fails to install

Tags: websphere-portal

I was trying to install IBM Form Experience Builder V 8.6 on Windows Server 2008 R2, but it fails with the following error:

Error during "post-install configure" phase

The error details as in the log file are as follows:

CRIMA1076E: Error executing the C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe command: status=1.
For more information, see the agent log file: C:\ProgramData\IBM\Installation Manager\logs\native\20150511_0026.log
Explanation: The Installation operation failed due to an error executing the exec command. An issue has occured with the package that cannot be resolved by installation Manager.

any help is appreciated.

Comment: Make sure you are installing with Administrator account and have rights to execute cmd.exe

Comment: Have you got any solution to this, I am facing same problem.

Answer (score -1):

I Got same issue , try to download IFixes of V8 add that to repository file while installing Portal and try to install portal with root or as a administrator.

Comment: I think the question is about Forms and not about Portal.